# Defining a function in Environ (Clojure) and then using it in code

Tags: clojure

I would like to be able to define an anonymous function in my Lieningen project using Environ.

Here is what that part of the project file looks like:

```
{:env {:foo (fn [s]
                (count s))}}
```

Then in my code, I would like to use that function. Something like:

```
(-> "here are a few words"
    (env :foo))
```

And then to get the size of `s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Environ will simply invoke [read-string](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/read-string) on the slurped file. The value at `:foo` will be a list containing the symbol `fn` followed by a vector with the symbol `s` inside and so on. i.e. the form has not been evaluated and so you will not be able to invoke the anonymous `fn`.

see [environ.core/read-env-file](https://github.com/weavejester/environ/blob/fb534773d16180078331b751abdfd970949bbe67/environ/src/environ/core.clj#L29)

Consider this:

```
(def f (read-string "(fn [s] (count s))"))

(f "test")
;; => ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

(def evaled-f (eval (read-string "(fn [s] (count s))")))
(evaled-f "test")
;; => 4
```

Also, your intended use is a little off. `->` is a macro that will take the first arg and "thread" it into the first position of the following form.

```
(macroexpand '(-> "here are a few words" (env :foo)))
;; => (env "here are a few words" :foo)
```

I think you're looking for something like:

```
(let [f (eval (env :foo))]
  (-> "here are a few words"
      f))
```

Comment: thanks for this wonderful explanation, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

`(env :foo)` returns list. To make function from it you can use `eval` or better macro like this:

```
(defmacro defn-env [fn-name env-key]
  `(def ~fn-name ~(env env-key)))

(defn-env env-fn :foo) ; => #'user/env-fn

(env-fn [1 2 3]) ; => 3
```

Note: if `(env :foo)` returns `nil` you need to add `:plugins [[lein-environ "1.0.0"]]` to your `project.clj`.